# Dolciani and Sorgenfrey textbook collaboration

Tags: secondary-education, textbooks, big-list

Would it be possible to get a complete list of math textbooks written jointly by Dr. Mary Dolciani and Dr. Robert Sorgenfrey?

I'm particularly interested in focusing on how they collaborated while writing their textbooks.

So far, all I can find is this list:

1. PreAlgebra: An Accelerated  Course
2. Algebra Structure and Method Book 1
3. Algebra and Trigonometry Structure and Method Book 2
4. Introductory Analysis

But absolutely nothing on the details of their collaboration.

Kindest regards, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the google search [Dolciani + Sorgenfrey + math + worldcat](https://www.google.com/search?q=Dolciani+Sorgenfrey+math+worldcat), where "worldcat" is the keyword for the type of information you're looking for. The top hit for me is [Showing all editions for 'Mathematics : structure and method course 2'](https://www.worldcat.org/title/mathematics-structure-and-method-course-2/oclc/24060829/editions).

Incidentally, the authors of these books varied over time and Sorgenfrey's name was not included in the original mid 1960s versions, nor on any of these 4 books I went through while I was in high school. (I went through all 4 books from Aug. 1973 to about March 1975, and the books themselves were variously dated from 1968 to maybe 1971 or 1972.) Indeed, the earlier versions had mostly different authors aside from Dolciani and slightly different titles (e.g. "Modern School Mathematics" was part of the title), but I suspect the content wasn't all that much different, maybe more pictures and updated real world references in the later versions. Also, I suspect that rather than a true co-author in the traditional sense, Sorgenfrey played more of the role of an adviser who double-checked certain content aspects. For all of Dolciani's books, [see this worldcat page](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=au%3ADolciani%2C+Mary+P.)